# I can SSH into the server remotely but the ubuntu 14.04 cannot ping the internet

Tags: ping, gateway

I've tried pinging google as well as 8.8.8.8. Neither works.

Results for cat /etc/network/interfaces

The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet static

```
address 18.207.0.91
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 18.207.0.0
broadcast 18.207.255.255
gateway 18.207.0.1
# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
dns-nameservers 18.71.0.151
```

I can ping other sites on the local network.

I can not ping the default gateway given.

Results for route -n

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         18.2.207.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em2
18.2.207.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 em2
18.207.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 em1

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit

```
 /etc/resolv.conf
```

With the desired name server. If you want to use Google just add

```
 8.8.8.8
```

Or based on info in question

```
 18.71.0.151
```

Save file. You may also want to remove the dns line

```
 dns-nameservers 18.71.0.151
```

from

```
 /etc/network/interfaces
```

and then restart networking

```
 sudo service networking restart
```

For multiple entries I forget if it a space or comma to separate them. Or maybe even on a new line.

Edit: You can put each dns server on a new line of file

Comment: Did this help? If so, can you please mark as accepted